# Why is there such big time difference in searching for element with higher index in ConcurrentBag?

Tags: c#, generics, concurrency, time-complexity

I was looking at different times for searching a specific element in ConcurrentBag with the use of .ElementAt() and found this strange time difference between searching for an element with an index of 950,000 and searching for an element with an index of 1,000,000.

The time it took to find the element on 950,000th place took between 62 and 68 milliseconds.
The time it took to find the element on 1,000,000th place took between 20 and 23 milliseconds.

And I'm not sure why that is.
The code looks like this:

```
ConcurrentBag<int?> concurrentBag = new ConcurrentBag<int?>();

int n = 1000000;
int? n1 = n;
for (int i = 0; i <= n1; i++)
{
     concurrentBag.Add(i);
}

DateTime before = DateTime.Now;
int? a = concurrentBag.ElementAt(n);
DateTime after = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan time = after - before;

Console.WriteLine(time.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Since `ConcurrentBag` represents an *unordered* collection of elements, I'm not sure what *relevance* using `ElementAt` with it would *have*. What *practical problem* are you trying to solve such that you think `ConcurrentBag` and accessing elements by index within it are part of the *solution*?

Comment: It's not any code that I was going to use afterwards, our teacher wanted us to prove time complexity for adding, removing, accessing and looking up elements in a few collections including ConcurrentBag. And this didn't make any sence to me.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not be using the `DateTime` library to check accuracy and benchmarks at this small of an interval.  When I run this code I get anywhere from 11ms to 70ms each time.  It's not going to be consistent.
2. You are doing one single lookup.  Your machine could be doing any number of other operations that would affect the speed of a single lookup.  You should run this code many thousand times and get the average to have any sort of valid data.

Comment: I was getting times for just a few various values from which I can evaluate the time complexity, but I'll keep that in mind, thanks.